# Can I vote to "Leave Open" a question?

Tags: discussion

There is a question that has a few "Close" vote. I think it should remain open.

Is there any way to express that besides upvoting or waiting for it to be closed and voting for reopening?

Comment: No, this feature has been requested  before, and never acted on. It's at least a little better now that edits throw closed questions into the Reopen queue - formerly, once a question gathered one upvote it was likely and with 2, basically guaranteed to be closed and forgotten.

Comment: See [How about a Vote not to close...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "Leave Open" feature/vote/flag; you have to wait for a question to be closed, then cast a re-open vote.

You *can* leave a comment addressed to the close-voters and would-be close-voters why you think the question is valid and should remain open.

Comment: ... and naturally clarifying the question so obviously no close-reason would apply does not need any waiting at all.